# How many ways are there to arrange a set of n objects into m spots with repetition and each of the n objects must appear at least once?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This is a generalized problem of a counting application I am currently trying to solve.

I am considering a set $S$ of `{e1, e2, e3}` and choosing a sequence, with repetition where every element appears at least once, of length 9.

First, I considered the ceiling of my solution: all the possible permutations of $S$ with repetition without restriction that every element appears at least once. Since there are 9 spots and each spot can be filled with 3 elements we have $3^9 = 19683$ possibilities.

Next, I considered placing each of the elements to fulfill the restriction that they must each occur at least once, then populated the remaining spots. In turn, $e_1$ can be placed in 9 spots, $e_2$ in 8 spots, $e_3$ can be placed in 7 spots. Finally, I can consider the remaining 6 spots with repetition without restriction, in $3^6$ ways. Since each of these steps can be performed regardless of the outcome of the previous step I apply the multiplication principle and get $9\times8\times7\times3^6=367416$. This is larger than the case without restriction so must be incorrect.

Therefore, given $n$ objects into $m$ spots where $m>n$ and each of the n elements must appear at least once. Why can I not place $n_1, n_2, n_3...$ in $m, m-1, m-2,...$ places respectively then populate the remaining spaces without restriction?

Comment: answering your final question: because then you count certain possibilities more than once.

Comment: There is a solution using Stirling numbers of the second kind. If you want a more fundamental calculation, you can find the number of ways using just one object or using exactly two, and subtract that from your $3^9$

Answer (score 1):

let $E$ the set of possibilities if there are no constraints.

For objects $e_1,\dots,e_n$ let $E_i$ denote the set of possibilities where object $e_i$ is not present.

Then to be found is:$$|E|-\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^nE_i\right|=n^m-\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^nE_i\right|$$

Now apply [PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and symmetry to find an expression for $\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^nE_i\right|$.